# Duda con diseño

Tags: html, css

estoy implementando una vista en front pero estoy teniendo un problema al desplazar con `margin-top` el contenedor que almacena el contenido de texto `about-content-container` dentro del contenedor principal `about-header-wrapper`.
**El problema que sucede es que al añadirle esa regla, el contenedor principal se desplaza pero no el contenedor de los textos(al que se le aplico el margin-top) dentro del principal**

```
    <div className="about-header-wrapper" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${bgAbout})`}}>
                    <div className="about-content-container">
                        <p className="about-content-title">
                            CONOCE NUESTRO EQUIPO
                        </p>
                        <p className="about-content-text">
                            Somos una empresa que nace de la pasión por la academia, la tecnología y la innovación.
                        </p>
                    </div>
      </div>
```

El sass:

```
    .about-header-wrapper
        height: 82vh
        max-width: 1280px
        margin: 0 auto
        background-size: contain
        background-repeat: no-repeat

        & > .about-content-container
            max-width: 50%
            margin: 20px auto
            
            & > .about-content-title
                width: 100%
                height: 58px
                margin: 0
                font-family: TitilliumWeb
                font-size: 2.7vw
                font-weight: 600
                font-stretch: normal
                font-style: normal
                line-height: 1.39
                letter-spacing: normal
                text-align: left
                color: #fff
                margin-bottom: 10px      


            & > .about-content-text
                max-width: 596px
                height: 63px
                font-family: TitilliumWeb
                font-size: 1.38vw
                font-weight: normal
                font-stretch: normal
                font-style: normal
                line-height: 1.6
                letter-spacing: normal
                text-align: left
                color: #fff
```